# Push detail controller from search display controller's table view

Tags: iphone, search, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I implemented a search option in my app but when I search something, I can't push a detail controller from the search display controller's table view.
Is there a way to do that?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume you have a `UISearchBarDelegate` method in a `UIViewController` called *SearchViewController*. To push `(DetailViewController*) dvc`, implement these methods in *SearchViewController*:

```
#pragma mark - Search bar delegate
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchTextMatchedSomeTarget) {
        textForDetailView = searchText;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:seguePushDetailView sender:self];
    }
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:seguePushDetailView]) {
        dvc = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        dvc.delegate = (id)self;
        dvc.searchText = textForDetailView;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Detail view controller protocol delegate
- (void)DetailViewControllerDidFinish:(DetailViewController *)controller
{
    NSString *somethingBackFromDetailView = controller.backToSearchView;
}
```

`UIDetailViewController` declares a *protocol* with the "did finish" method and properties of whatever type you like, both to receive data from *SearchViewController* and to send back any data after any detail processing. The segue is added in Xcode IB by control dragging from `UISearchViewController` to `UIDetailViewController`. **NB:** the segue source and destination are the view controllers themselves. That way they can be invoked programmatically as opposed to automatic invocation on a tap event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Will this code work even if I'm not using storyboards? And I don't need to get back data from my detail controller so I don't need its protocol.